# find the not null, finite sets $\mathbb{A}$, of real numbers, with $f(\mathbb{A})\subset \mathbb{A}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=\frac{2}{3}(4^x-x^2-1)$. Show that f is increasing and find the not null, finite sets $A$, of real numbers, with $f(A)\subset A$. I easily accomplished the first task by simply differentiating the function, but I don't understand what I am asked to do for the second and why it hepls me to know the monotonicity of the function.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** The second derivative of $f(x) - x$ is an increasing function, so $f$ has no more than three fixed points, but by inspection, $0, \pm \frac{1}{2}$ are fixed points of $f$, so all of the (nonempty) subsets of $\{-\frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2}\}$ meet the criterion. Now, show that for any point $a$ not in those subsets $a, f(a), f^2(a), \ldots$ is a strictly increasing or strictly decreasing sequence, so that any set satisfying $A \ni a$ and $f(A) \subseteq A$ is infinite.